# To use boost::object_pool to implement custom allocator for map, How to allocate n continuous elements using boost::object_pool?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, allocator

I want to specify `allocator` for `std::map`. So writing custom one, taking base code from [here](http://www.josuttis.com/cppcode/allocator.html) by Josuttis. I want to use `boost::object_pool` to get high performance. But `boost::object_pool` does not provide API to allocate `n` continuous elements which is required by interface function

`pointer allocate (size_type num, const void* = 0)`

of the `allocator`.

How to allocate n number of continuous elements in `boost::objet_pool`? Any other open source object pool provides same functionality.

I see `boost::simple_segregated_storage` has interface

`void * malloc_n(size_type n, size_type partition_sz);`

but

```
void free_n(void * chunks, size_type n,size_type partition_sz);
```

requires the size of allocated elements and I do not think that could easily used as object pool.

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is pure hack to use `boost::object_pool` to implement the custom `allocator` for the `std::map`. One need to test the solution on the platform (particular version OS, compiler, boost and c++std lib combination).

It seems that `std::map`, never requests the continuous memory for more than one element, so you can implement alloctor's API `pointer allocate (size_type num, const void* = 0)` to allocate only single element ie, pair of `key-value`, as `num` is always going to be 1.

I checked the case of inserting multiple elements, copy constructor of the map, inserting multiple elements into the map with single call to `map::insert` passing range of elements using `begin iterator` and `end iterator` of another map.

tested it on RHEL7, boost 1.57.0, gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)

Comment: Huh. What solution? What does `map` have to do with your question? And, yeah, **of** course `map` doesn't allocate multiple nodes at a time (it's node-based and the iterator/reference invalidation rules imply it shouldn't, unless you are willing to risk bad fragmentation scenarios, a.k.a. resource leaks)

Comment: @sehe: problem was, I wanted to build allocater for std::map using boost::object_pool. but boost object pool is required to support continuous  `n`  no of elements chunk to support standard allocator interface. But it could be hacked for `std::map` to support only allocate 1 element at a time as that is the only requirement from std::map to allocator